# WebRTC over Local Network

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, webrtc

I'm building a React website that I want to use WebRTC to basically be able to make audio/video calls to other devices, **only on my local network**.  Because the `getUserMedia` requires HTTPS, I'm running into issues whereby I basically have to bypass the SSL warnings (the "visit website anyway" buttons), which I don't want to do.

I'm using my laptop to act as the connection broker/signaling server to allow the clients to connect with each other--if I downgrade the capabilities to HTTP for text chat only, this works great--but the whole purpose is to use audio/video, so I need that SSL layer.

**My question is:** how do I setup the SSL layer properly so that I don't have to bypass the warnings and accept a self-signed certificate?

Strictly speaking, the self-signed certificate does work and I can do this using it, but it seems self-defeating, so it's not really the way I want to go.

Again, this is **only** for **intranet** usage, so I don't know if that makes it easier or harder, but that's my constraint.

**EDIT:**
The server is written in NodeJS.  I've found some documentation suggesting that Node can be given additional CAs (e.g. `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS`).  Is this something that I can leverage?  Would a client html page utilize this in any meaningful way?

This link seems promising: https://engineering.circle.com/https-authorized-certs-with-node-js-315e548354a2.  The main thing I'm not understanding is how I would utilize that `ca: fs.readFileSync('ca-crt.pem')` line for a given request, as it seems like the code there is actually making the request (but one would have already been made to the server in my case, no?).  https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback seems to indicate something similar, as well.

Comment: `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` is for the certs nodejs is willing to accept when it is acting as a client, you have the opposite problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is totally possible to register a domain name, and then point it at something in the Private Address Range. I do this for local development sometimes. I registered `pion.io` and got a wildcard cert via LetsEncrypt.

You could also use [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert). Then either in `/etc/hosts` or in your router itself you can give a FQDN to your signaling/web server.

There is also the `--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` argument for Chromium, I haven't used it lately though not sure if it still works.